# Fonction skip bool and doesn't calculate

Tags: python, function, input, boolean, operators

Welcome in my misery.

I'm a novice/beginner in coding :)
I've been trying to write a calculator that detects
anomalies in the input provided.

My first problem was to neglect any letters and
that was easily fixed with .isalpha() .

Now my second problem is to keep symbols (such as: !@#$%?)
away. I looked up code from here to try and solve it
by creating a string (sym) with symbols then comparing num1
and num2 with it to see if there was any of the unwanted
symbols in them. If there were, it'll set a bool (NoSym) to
false and conclude by verifying the value of NoSym to
say if the function should eval or no.

But now if I try to run it, the system will just skip
over verifying checkpoint or doing the math.

I'll gladly accept any help since I want to
develop my programming skills for my future project :)

The code:

```
sym = "!@#$%?"
fo = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
NoSym = True

def calc():
   cal = input()

#(...)

   if cal == "*":
       num1 = input("num1 - ")
       num2 = input("num2 - ")
       if num1.isalpha() or num2.isalpha():
           print("No variables.")
           calc()
       for i in sym:
           if i in num1 or num2:
               NoSym = False
               break
       if NoSym == False:
           print("No symbols")
       else:
           num1 = float(num1)
           num2 = float(num2)
           ans = num1 * num2
           print(ans)
           calc()
   if cal != fo[0] and fo[1] and fo[2] and fo[3]:
       print("no")
       calc()
```

---

Comment: `and` and `or` don't work the way they do in English.  This has been asked a thousand times but I don't know a duplicate.

Comment: `if i in num1 or num2` is `True` unless `num2` is an empty string.

Comment: You should probably avoid recursion for this exercise. Also, give some examples of input values that you consider to be valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not initialize the variable `NoSym = True` before checking whether the condition for it to be false was met, so put `NoSym = True` in the line before the `for i in sym:`.
And I think it's better to use regex to check for invalid characters, something like this:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'[^!@#\$%\?]')

s = 'agbnjash!gg@@#$$%?ii#'

for i in s:
     if bool(re.search(p,i)):
          print(i)
```

Result:

```
a
g
b
n
j
a
s
h
g
g
i
i
```

If you want num1 and num2 to be formatted by digits only (including decimal numbers), you can do something like this:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^\d+(\.\d+)?$')

num1 = '4556tree888'
num2 = '76673.98'

if bool(re.search(p,num1)) and bool(re.search(p,num2)):
    print('Calculate')
else:
    print('Please input valid numbers')
```

The last thing I would like to say is about this line:

```
if cal != fo[0] and fo[1] and fo[2] and fo[3]:
```

Change it to:

```
if cal != fo[0] and calc != fo[1] and calc != fo[2] and calc != fo[3]:
```

Comment: You don't need `bool`. Whenever `if <condition>` occurs, if `<condition>` is not already a Boolean, it gets converted.